# apply xsl to merge two xml files in jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt

I made a xsl merge two xml to one, then using the output to another xsl  for a html view.

When I use xmlSpy to test it, it works very well, but when I put them under a java web application, somethings is wrong.

The xsl is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"  />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:variable name="xsdresult" select="document('xsdResult.xml')" />
  <xsl:variable name="schresult" select="document('result.xml')" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:result-document href="fullresult.xml" method="xml">
        <fullresult> 
           <xsl:copy-of select="$schresult/node()" />  
           <xsl:copy-of select="$xsdresult/node()" />     
        </fullresult>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this file and xml files are all under the same directory and the output file is the same.

A jsp to apply this xslt:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <%@ page language="java"  contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/xsl-1.0" prefix="xsl"%>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <%@ page%>

    <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
   <p>
  <xsl:apply xml="WEB-INF/classes/result/result.xml" xsl="WEB-INF/classes/result/merge.xsl" />
 <xsl:apply xml="WEB-INF/classes/result/xsdResult.xml" xsl="WEB-INF/classes/result/merge.xsl" />
 <xsl:apply xml="WEB-INF/classes/result/fullresult.xml" xsl="WEB-INF/classes/result/anotherone.xsl" />
   </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is in the merge.xsl, document('xsdResult.xml') and document('result.xml'), they are always searching under eclipse_home directory, not the tomcat webapps direcotry.

Comment: So do you have a question? What is it?

Comment: the problem is in the merge.xsl, document('xsdResult.xml') and document('result.xml') , they are always searching under eclipse_home directory, not the tomcat webapps direcotry.

Comment: Yes, but this is a statement -- not a question. Also, you could just placethe files where they are expected to be -- so this even isn't a problem.

Comment: yeah  i place them correctly  but something goes wrong..

Comment: Something goes wrong? Like it suddenly starts raining?

Comment: Another note: You are using XSLT 2.0 -- it most probably isn't supported in your environment (typically only XSLT 1.0 is supported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the [URI Resolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html). Looking at [what happens inside the ApplyTag](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/taglibs/xsl/ApplyTag.java.htm) I don't see how you would be able to provide your own.

There seems to be another Apache taglib for doing similar things - [xtags](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/xtags-doc/index.html). The `StyleTag` in there seems to do a better job compared to the `ApplyTag`, it *is* using an URI Resolver (look at [line 154](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/taglibs/xtags/xslt/StyleTag.java.htm)). However, I don't see a clean way to pass your own without subclassing from it. You may trace the code further into the [URLHelper](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/taglibs/xtags/util/URLHelper.java.htm) and see if modifying the URI within the `document()` function to be something like `/WEB-INF/...` will yield better results.

That said, however, you will very likely run into another issue with the second step of your transformation where you expect to pick up the result of the first pass from the file system. Where to will the first pass dump the `fullresult.xml`? does the process the application server runs on behalf of have permissions to write to the file system in there? Do you even want it to write to the file system?

I feel like you would be much better off putting together a small utility class in plain Java that would pipe your transformations using JAXP API. You would have all the control you want over parser features including the URI resolution and you wouldn't need to use filesystem as an intermediate store. And when you do that, you can also consider running your transformation in a single pass. You can merge your documents into a `xsl:variable` and then apply templates on it or just apply templates to the result of each `document()` function individually. Unless, of course, you need to retain the result of the XML merge as well.

Hope it helps

Comment: is there any example shows that append a xml file to another one directly using jaxp api?

Comment: assuming your XML files are small and you are not running thousands of these in parallel (so you don't worry too much about using memory) you can just use the DOM API (here's one tutorial but you can find more if you google for JAXP: http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/dom.html). You would either create a new Document, create a root node and then append the other two as child nodes or modify one adding the content of another one. I was actually suggesting you keep your XSLT and just move the logic out of the JSP into the Java class. makes sense?

Comment: what do you mean by keeping xslt?

Comment: keeping your current approach of merging the two XMLs through transformation. I suggested you moved from the old taglib to a plan java implementation that would run your transformations as you designed them. Your JSP page would basically use that Java class to do the job. I hope it makes sense. If you by some reason have to use the taglibs you're using then I don't see a way to provide the URI resolver. You would end up extending it in one way or another.

Comment: @user1021885 if (and only if) my answer helped you in any way please consider accepting it or at least upvoting it.